# Meaning of the words "act on level terms"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What do the words "acting on level terms" mean in the following context:

"... whether the term is a standard term, not merely in similar non-negotiable contracts, but in commercial contracts freely negotiated between parties **acting on level terms** and at arms' length;..."?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This question may be a better fit for [Law Stack Exchange](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://law.stackexchange.com/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiZzfrXpN_tAhUhzIUKHWuDDroQFjAAegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3vrwqSb6Wny6Ce3bVO2c8u), but in general, "level terms" refers to a situation where no one has an advantage: everyone is equal and the situation is fair. I suspect this may have a more specific and nuanced meaning in law (I know "arm's length" definitely does).

In everyday language, "on a level playing field" is a more common variation.